# PanResponder could not detect touch if i touch on Touchables(TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback)

Tags: react-native

I have implemented **PanResponder** in my project but it only works when I touch non touchable elements . When I touch touchable elements like **TouchableOpacity**, PanReponder does not responds.But when I move my finger on **TouchableOpacity** PanResponder responds.

> Same thing happening for Button also

Please tell me what might be the problem.

Expo Link : https://snack.expo.io/SyYrtq87W

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, PanResponder, View, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    show : false
  };
  _panResponder = {};

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({

      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        alert('clicked')
        console.log('clicked')
        return true
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        alert('moved')
        console.log('moved')
        return true
      },
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}
        collapsable={false}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>

 {/*********************PanResponder does not respond***************************/}       

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{width:200, height:200,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>



        <Button
          title="Here is a button for some reason"
          onPress={() => {}}  
        />

  {/*****************************************************************************/}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

Comment: The github issue you shared says the opposite of what you are talking about, or you really need to rephrase your question. `When I touch touchable elements like TouchableOpacity, it does not responds` - who doesn't respond? The touchable or the responder?

Comment: Sorry for that.  It is PanResponder which is not responding. Touchable is working fine.

Comment: In the link you provided the issue is that the Touchables aren't responding so it's a different issue.
I think the responder is working correctly for you, if you want touchables not to respond you can disable their pointer events.

Comment: The responder is not responding correctly on. If I press on TouchableOpacity (red box in app) no alert pops up. If I drag my finger even a little(and sometimes even on click) on that red box alert pops up with message 'moved' indicating that finger is moved on it. What I want is, if I click on that red box alert should pop up with message 'clicked'

Comment: Oh if that's the case the link you added works just like that for me on iOS. In what platform do you get this issue?

Comment: I have checked both on iOS and android but none worked for me. Did you get popup alert with message 'clicked' when you clicked on red box? I got popup alert with message 'clicked' when I press anywhere other than red box and blue button

Comment: Yes but it was on simulator. But I just remember I had the same issue a few months ago with PanResponder and I figured a way around it. I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: No, I have tested on actual device, PanResponder does not responds if touch is made on Touchables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally It hit me. It was a very silly mistake.
forgot to add `alert('clicked')`  at

```
onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: ()
```

Now,

`onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {alert('clicked') ; return false},`

Expo Link : https://snack.expo.io/ryWx7lBrb

Now, it takes touch everywhere, including Touchables and Buttons.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, PanResponder, View, StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    show : false
  };
  _panResponder = {};

  componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({

      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => {
        alert('clicked')
        return true
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {alert('clicked') ; return false},
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
      onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
      onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}
        collapsable={false}
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>

 {/*********************PanResponder now responds***************************/}       

        <TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{width:200, height:200,backgroundColor:'red'}}>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>



        <Button
          title="Here is a button for some reason"
          onPress={() => {}}  
        />

  {/*****************************************************************************/}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't work for me, if I try to scroll the alert is triggered

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue. Basically because you always return true in `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` and/or `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` they will take command over that touch event.

My workaround: Don't consider the touch "yours" (PanResponder's) unless the user moved it a little first by a threshold you set.

```
const touchThreshold = 20;
const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder : () => false,
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder : (e, gestureState) => {
        const {dx, dy} = gestureState;

        return (Math.abs(dx) > touchThreshold) || (Math.abs(dy) > touchThreshold);
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: You provided the solution of the opposite of what I was asking. My problem is If I touch touchables, PanResponder does not respond, Touchables responded fine. In my case Touchables took command over PanResponder

Comment: In your case PanResponder took command over other touch events, but in my case Touchables took command over PanResponder.

Comment: This was the solution I wanted. Do note you can do `(e, {dx, dy}) => {` instead of `(e, gestureState) => { const {dx, dy} = gestureState;`

Answer (score 3):

Touchables will not work if you set this

`onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true`

This will entirely take control over the touches. It is always a good option to take control only if the user starts dragging the component.

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true
```

Here is an example for PanResponder.

```
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
        if (gesture.dy > 0 && this.state.size._value < width) {
          this.state.size.setValue(40 + gesture.dy)
        }
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.size, {
          toValue: 40
        }).start()
      }
    })
```

This is my JSX code.

```
<Animated.View {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.openImage}>
        <Animated.Image style={profileImage}
           source={{uri: 'https://example.com/face.jpg'}}/>
     </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
 </Animated.View>
```

[image]